# SystemVerilog TypeDef Can;t index object with zero packed or unpacked array dimensions

Tags: verilog, typedef, fpga, system-verilog

I am currently attempting to use TypeDef in SystemVerilog in order to define a new data structure object containing a 8 bit unsigned register and an 32-bit signed integer but I keep getting the error:

*Error (10053): Verilog HDL error at UART.v(35): can't index object "data" with zero packed or unpacked array dimensions*

I have recreated a simple implementation below where the topLevelModule instances a lowLevelModule which determines the values of both the integer and 8-bit unsigned register in which the structure is made up of and outputs them to the topLevelModule.

Using a separate UART module I am attempting to send this structure/object (which is 40bits long) to  a host computer- to simplify the code below I have omitted this module and left out the majority of the non-associated code.

```
typedef struct {
            reg[7:0] identifier;
            integer currentSynapticWeight;
        } dataPacket;

module topLevel(clk, reset, UART_TXD);

    input clk; // Clock Signal
    input reset; // Reset Signal
    output UART_TXD; // Output Signal

    dataPacket data; // Instance the dataPacket Object

    lowLevelModule LLM1(clk, reset, data);

    // CODE TO DRIVE THE UART CONNECTION OMMITED

endmodule

module lowLevelModule(clk, reset, data);

    input clk; // Clock Signal
    input reset; // Reset Signal
    output dataPacket data; // Instance the dataPacket Object

    reg[7:0] someUnsigned8BitUnsignedReg = 8'b10001000;
    integer someIntegerValue = 25;

    always @(*)
        begin
            data[39:32] = someUnsigned8BitUnsignedReg;
            data[31:0]  = someIntegerValue;
        end

endmodule
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am not sure if I have used TypeDef in the correct manor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `data` as an unpacked structure - you cannot access it as an integral packed array. Either change your assignments to unpacked members of the struct:

```
data.identifier = someUnsigned8BitUnsignedReg;
data.currentSynapticWeight  = someIntegerValue;
```

Or change your `typedef` to define a packed struct

```
typedef struct packed {
            reg[7:0] identifier;
            integer currentSynapticWeight;
        } dataPacket;
```